# User uploading multiple images?

Tags: python, django, image-uploading

I'm making web app that sell used bikes and I can't figure out how to enable user to upload multiple images. At the moment it is possible to upload only one image.Thanks in advance!

Here is my model.py:

```
class UsedBike(models.Model):

manufacturer = models.CharField("Proizvođač", 
max_length = 20, choices = manufacturers,)  #proizvodjac
model = models.CharField("Model:", max_length = 20) #model
engine_size = models.IntegerField("Kubikaža:", default = 0) #kubikaza
km = models.IntegerField("Kilometraža:", default = 0)   #kilometraza
year = models.IntegerField("Godina proizvodnje:", default = 0)  #godina proizvodnje
bike_type = models.CharField("Vrsta motora:", max_length = 20, choices = bike_types)    #tip motora
location = models.CharField("Lokacija:", max_length = 20)   #lokacija
comment = models.TextField("Komentar:") #opis
views = models.IntegerField("Broj pregleda:", default = 0)  #broj pregleda
likes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)    #broj lajkova
slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)  #slug
hp = models.IntegerField("Snaga", default = 0)  #snaga
condition = models.CharField("Stanje:", max_length = 15, choices = condition_of_bike)   #stanje
price = models.IntegerField("Cena:", default = 0)   #cena
registered = models.CharField("Registrovan:", max_length = 15, choices = yes_no)    #registrovan
img = models.ImageField("Slike:", upload_to = 'img', blank = True, null = True)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable = False, default = timezone.now())
expire_date = models.DateTimeField(editable = False, default = timezone.now()+datetime.timedelta(days = 30))
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms.py:

```
class BikeForm(forms.ModelForm):

helper = FormHelper()
helper.layout = Layout(
    Div(
        Div('manufacturer', 'model', 'engine_size', 'km', 'year', 'bike_type', 'location',
        css_class = 'col-md-6'),
        Div(AppendedText('hp', 'ks'), 'condition', AppendedText('price', '€'), 'registered', 'comment', Field('img', multiple = 'multiple'),
        ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Dodaj', css_class = 'btn btn-primary')),  css_class = 'col-md-6'),

        css_class = 'row-fluid'),
    )

class Meta:
    model = UsedBike
    widgets = {
        'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 6, 'cols': 1}),
    }
    exclude = ('views', 'likes', 'slug', 'author')
```

views.py:

```
def add_bike(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BikeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():

        form = form.save(commit = False)
        form.author = request.user
        form.save()

        if 'img' in request.FILES:
            form.img = request.FILES['img']
        form.save()

        return index(request)

    else:
        print form.errors

else:
    form = BikeForm()

return render(request, 'shop/add_bike.html', { 'form': form })
```

And my form in template:

```
<form class = 'form' enctype = 'multipart/form-data' role = 'form' id = 'bike_form' method = 'post' action = '/shop/add_bike/' >
<h2>Postavi oglas</h2>

{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}

</form>
```

Comment: Is there a MAX amount of images you would allow a user to upload? If that is the case, you can simply make `img`, `img1`, `img2`... fields in your model, and add another `if 'img[NUMBER]' in request.FILES:` to your view.

Comment: Thank you @Hybrid. I want to allow user to upload max 5 images. But how can I save 5 images from one form field?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on django-photologues' source code. It has an option to upload an arbitrary number of images in a zip file https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue